# find the latest appointment date for the same person

Tags: sql

I want to create a new column, which shows the latest appointment date for the same HC_Number.Example: HC_Number- 2552 has 3 appointments in december- 2nd december, 7th december and 25th december. So the new column showing latest appointment will show 25th december for both the records on 2nd & 7th december.

```
Select 
a.HC_NUMBER
,a.APPOINTMENT_TYPE_FULL
,a.APPOINTMENT_DATE
,a.person_id
,a.APPT_BOOKED_BY

FROM [HIM_Clinical].[dbo].[APPOINTMENT_DATA] a (nolock) -----Main Data----

left join [ODS_CCL].[dbo].[ODS_CCL_ENCOUNTER] e (nolock) on a.ENCNTR_ID=e.ENCNTR_ID

WHERE a.APPOINTMENT_TYPE_FULL like '%Smart Checkup%'
AND a.Appointment_Status IN ('Checked Out','Checked In','No Show','Confirmed')
AND a.APPOINTMENT_DATE>='2020-12-01' AND a.APPOINTMENT_DATE<='2020-12-31'
```

Comment: What is your DBMS? From the SQL, this looks like SQL Server. Is this correct? Please tag SQL questions always with the DBMS you are using, as the answer may heavily depend on this. With many DBMS, you can even tag the version you are using to help us further. Tags for this request could be `sql` `sql-server` `sql-server-2017` for example.

Comment: On a side note: What is the reason you are using `nolock` on the tables? Are you trying to address some issue or is it just because you have seen it done so elsewhere? You should probably remove this. Read https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere.

Comment: you can use outer apply which will query max appointment date value for each hc number   `select hc_number, m.lastappointmentdate from yourtable a   outer apply ( select top 1 m.appointment_date as lastappointmentdate from yourtable b on b.hc_number = a.hc_number order by appointment_date desc) m`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) to get latest appointment date column for each HC_NUMBER with `MAX(a.APPOINTMENT_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY a.HC_NUMBER) AS LATEST_APPOINTMENT_DATE`.

Try like below.

```
Select a.HC_NUMBER
        ,a.APPOINTMENT_TYPE_FULL
        ,a.APPOINTMENT_DATE
        ,a.person_id
        ,a.APPT_BOOKED_BY
        ,MAX(a.APPOINTMENT_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY a.HC_NUMBER) AS LATEST_APPOINTMENT_DATE

FROM [HIM_Clinical].[dbo].[APPOINTMENT_DATA] a (nolock) -----Main Data----

left join [ODS_CCL].[dbo].[ODS_CCL_ENCOUNTER] e (nolock) on a.ENCNTR_ID=e.ENCNTR_ID

WHERE a.APPOINTMENT_TYPE_FULL like '%Smart Checkup%'
    AND a.Appointment_Status IN ('Checked Out','Checked In','No Show','Confirmed')
    AND a.APPOINTMENT_DATE>='2020-12-01'
    AND a.APPOINTMENT_DATE<='2020-12-31'
```

---

Alternatively you can use `inner sql` query with `GROUP BY` `HC_NUMBER` & `MAX(APPOINTMENT_DATE)` then join it with your table as below.

```
Select a.HC_NUMBER
        ,a.APPOINTMENT_TYPE_FULL
        ,a.APPOINTMENT_DATE
        ,a.person_id
        ,a.APPT_BOOKED_BY
        ,latest.APPOINTMENT_DATE AS LATEST_APPOINTMENT_DATE

FROM [HIM_Clinical].[dbo].[APPOINTMENT_DATA] a (nolock) -----Main Data----

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT HC_NUMBER, MAX(APPOINTMENT_DATE) AS APPOINTMENT_DATE
    FROM [HIM_Clinical].[dbo].[APPOINTMENT_DATA] (nolock)
    GROUP BY HC_NUMBER
) latest ON latest.HC_NUMBER = a.HC_NUMBER

left join [ODS_CCL].[dbo].[ODS_CCL_ENCOUNTER] e (nolock) on a.ENCNTR_ID=e.ENCNTR_ID

WHERE a.APPOINTMENT_TYPE_FULL like '%Smart Checkup%'
    AND a.Appointment_Status IN ('Checked Out','Checked In','No Show','Confirmed')
    AND a.APPOINTMENT_DATE>='2020-12-01'
    AND a.APPOINTMENT_DATE<='2020-12-31'
```

Comment: You are missing an alias for `MAX(APPOINTMENT_DATE)` in the second query.

Comment: this work's, but can we also amend this to identify any future dated appointments ? if this same patient has an appt in february.

Comment: Second query will work to get appt in February also. Add necessary conditions if needed in `inner query`.